# jQuery: event "mouseover"-like

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need an event, that invokes everytime I move my mouse above some HTML element. But I need it to fire off all the time I am moving, not just when I enter some element (like the mouseover, mouseenter or hover event does).

I saw a lot of people were trying to do just opposite functionality few years ago (mouseover element was firing of all the time I was hovering above some div) but everytime I was testing this event, it fired off only when I entered some div. I need it to fire off everytime I move my mouse and I am above watched element so I can determine mouse relative position to that element.

Is there an event I am missing or is there some workaround how to track mouse position within some element based just on hovering(not click, dbclick, ..)?

Comment: `mousemove` ???  BTW, you should always check the DOC: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: Yes, thats it. Oh my god, Im sorry I didnt work it out by myself, I tried literally every event but this one and this is how it ends. Thank you very much, I feel very ashamed right now

Comment: No reason to be ashamed, now you know where to look ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the mouseover event, then bind to the mousemove.
I made you a small example to see the coordinates while you are moving over a div.

```
$("#mydiv").bind('mousemove', function(event) 
{ 
    var offsetleft = this.offsetLeft;
    var offsettop = this.offsetTop;
    var coordX = event.pageX - offsetleft;
    var coordY = event.pageY - offsettop;
    $("#coords").html("X: " + coordX + " Y: " + coordY);                                 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dVqwH/2/

Comment: Very nice and usefull, Thank you!

Comment: Thank you also, I just updated it to give you the coordinates of the mouse pointer inside the div, and not the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use mousemove: http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

```
$( "#target" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
  msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>" + msg + "</div>" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can bind to the [mousemove jQuery event](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)

```
$( "html" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  ...
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Zwj/3/)

In the examples I bind to all the document but you can easily bind to the element of interest with [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Except, that you bind it to your HTML-element, and not `body`.